# Accusative or nominative case after "wie"/"als"

Tags: grammatical-case

What should be the case after "wie"/"als", as in the following examples?

> Er sieht aus wie ein/einen Amerikaner.
>
> Sie ist besser als ihr/ihren Freund.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Comparisons are in their essence always comparisons of activities. In other words, the words that "manage" the comparison coordinate verbs. In German, these words are (mainly) "wie" and "als" and they function as subordinating conjunctions. Only that the clause they introduce is stripped off the verb because it would be super redundant.

> Ich bin größer(,) als sie (ist).
>
> Er ist genau so groß(,) wie ich (bin).

This verb-fundament is also the reason for the seemingly exceptional sentence structure.
Just as a side note... the verb is only skipped if it is doubled. Sometimes it has to be there.

> Ich hat mehr gegessen, als ich erwartet habe.

What does that  for the cases? Well, conjunction do not have any effect on cases so the cases are entirely governed by the verb, or better, the context.

In your example the things you compare both have the function of subject for the verb.

> Er sieht aus (,) wie ein Amerikaner aussieht.

And in this case it is impossible to construct a context that allows for a different setting. But in general, it is possible:

> Ich sehe sie öfter als (ich) ihn (sehe).
> I see her more often than (I see) him.
>
> Ich sehe sie öfter als er (sie sieht).
> I see her more often than he (does).

For a more detailed look on comparisons in German, check [out this post on my blog](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/02/17/comparisons-german/).

Answer (score 7):

I would say it's Nominativ. Your examples would be:

```
Er sieht aus wie ein Amerikaner.

Sie ist besser als ihr Freund.
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always a word standing in nominative or a nominal phrase (noun phrase).

**If things are equal**
If the both parts that you compare are equal, you use `wie` + nominative:

> Der Baum ist so hoch ***wie*** das gelbe Haus. (»das gelbe Haus« is a nominal phrase)
>   Das Gebäude brannte ***wie*** Zunder. (»Zunder« is a noun standing in nominative)

In the last example you could theoretically say `wie der Zunder` or `wie ein Zunder`, aber `brennen wie Zunder` is a verbal phrase where `Zunder` has no Article. (»Zunder« = engl. "tinder")

**If equality is negated**
You have to use `wie` also if equality is negated:

> Warte auf mich, ich bin *nicht* so schnell ***wie*** du. (»du« is a personal pronoun standing in nominative)

**if things are different**
If the things that are compared are different (i.e. if the adjective is not used as a positive but as a comparative), then you have to use `als` + nominative:

> Heinz ist *größer **als** Lisa.* (»größer« is a comparative, so you have to use »als«, and »Lisa« is a name in nominative)
>   Sie ist *besser **als** ihr Freund.* (»besser« is a comparative forcing the use of »als«, »ihr Freund« is a nominal phrase)

A negated difference is built the same way as a normal difference:

> Der Tisch war *nicht teurer **als** der Stuhl.* (»nicht« is a negation, »teurer« is a comparative who forces »als« and »der Stuhl« is a nominal phrase)

Answer (score 1):

In your examples "wie/als" refers to the subjects of the sentences: "**Er** (wer?) sieht aus", "**Sie** (wer?) ist besser". Thus in other contexts, other cases are possible, e.g.

- Er kennt **sie** (wen?) besser als ihren Feund. = Er kennt ihren Freund einigermaßen. Er kennt sie sehr gut.
- **Er** (wer?) kennt sie besser als ihr Freund. = Ihr Freund kennt sie einigermaßen. Er kennt sie sehr gut.

Likewise

- **Er** behandelt sie wie ein Bruder.
- Sie behandelt **ihn** wie einen Bruder.